# Memcached still listening, even after uninstalling (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, memcached

I installed memcached on Ubuntu 18.04 like this:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
```

I then uninstalled it like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove memcached
```

It did successfully uninstall. If I try again then I'm told that it is not installed.

However, it still seems to be listening, or something:

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep memcached
tcp       14      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3880/memcached
tcp6       0      0 :::11211                :::*                    LISTEN      3302/memcached
```

What's up with that? How do I get rid of it completely?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server got rid of those listening ports, or whatever they were.